# Ubuntu 18.04 speakers quality problem

Tags: drivers, sound, soundcard, speakers, ubuntu-drivers

I have just installed Ubuntu and I am still dealing with the initial setup. The problem I face is the quality sound quality of my speakers. All sounds outputted seem like a phone call with a very bad signal. Until now I have done the following:

> Updated the sound card drivers following instructions from here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting - nothing fixed.
>
> Followed the instructions in this fix: [Laptop's speakers sound bad. Poor sound quality](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108825/laptops-speakers-sound-bad-poor-sound-quality?newreg=aa77ee6018144c0fb2fbd441c3631a5a) - solved the same issue I was facing with connected headphones and HDMI receivers.
>
> Tried external sound card - worked fine, perfect sound quality.

Is there anything I can try to fix the speakers issue too?

edit: the result of command `sudo lshw -c multimedia` is:

```
  *-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus information: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:c2600000-c2603fff
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -c multimedia`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did.