# very bad sound quality + weird behaviour

Tags: sound

very bad and unpleasant sound quality. And the weird thing is- keeping volume 100% or below vanishes bad quality issue. However keeping volume at 100% or below, unusually produce very low volume sound which is tough to hear from a bit distant(abnormal). And as i increase volume after 100%, sound loudness increase drastically(pretty much like normal now), however bad sound+unwanted noise problem appear.

*This problem started after not properly shutting down the pc(pulled power cable without shutting down). then few days later there was no sound at all. Today after reinstalling the os, the same bad sound problem showed up.*

I tried this answer-
[Laptop's speakers sound bad. Poor sound quality](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108825/laptops-speakers-sound-bad-poor-sound-quality/1108826#1108826)

it didnt work. and also didnt find `enable-lfe-remixing = no`(2nd portion 4th line in that answer) in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf.

And from this answer- [How do I debug issues with Pulse Audio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201780/how-do-i-debug-issues-with-pulse-audio/202533#202533)
doing `pulseaudio -D` resulted in
**E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.**

Comment: Poor quality sound is usually a problem with hardware or cables/connections.  If the problem is software-based, generally it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Sound quality was normal before the mentioned improper shut down.  Anyway will check with spare speaker.

Comment: i checked the sound box with phone and it works just fine.