# Poor sound quality on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, speakers, pipewire

The sound quality of my laptop's speakers is much worse in Ubuntu 21.10 compared to Windows. I've tried some soultions like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108825/laptops-speakers-sound-bad-poor-sound-quality), however I [found out](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/qcei0m/is_pulseaudio_dying/) that Ubuntu recently switched from PulseAudio to PipeWire and therefore most of the info I can find is out of date. Is there a solution for this?

If thats of any help here is the output of `pactl info`:

```
§ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 6
Tile Size: 65472
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 15.0
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo
Cookie: b048:c920
```